# Is it appropriate to use named routes in integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Which one of these is the "right" way to write integration (requests) tests.

```
it "should be successful" do
  get "/about/terms"
  response.should be_success
end

it "should be successful" do
  get about_terms_path
  response.should be_success
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The `about_terms_path` is correct because the custom route path may change in the routes file but the name of the route should stay the same.

The former would lead to brittle tests.

If the name of the route changed, all references to that route in the Rails app would need changing and so would your rspec tests.

If the path of the route changed, nothing in your Rails app or rspec tests would need changing.

**EDIT:**

If you want to test the routes, check this out https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs

Comment: I agree that named routes are the way to go, but maybe for a slightly different reason. I would say that the vernacular of your application code should match the vernacular of your test code. Since Rails wants you to use named routes in your application, it seems to me that it would be logical to use named routes in your tests.

Answer (score 3):

I would say either is okay, and I personally prefer the first one.

Integration test is to mimic human's eyes and actions. Human being could see "/about/terms", but not "about_term_path".

Besides, two suggestions:

1. Better to use Capybara which allow web driver with Javascript. In that way, "get" won't work, instead, use "visit"
2. No need to check response in integration test, which is the job of functional test(controller). Go to the real point directly.

**Add**

To answer Jason's question. Yes, I always use hard coded routes in integration tests, quite consistently.

The reason is the **outside-in approach**, which is the key point of Acceptance Tests Driven Development. When I write integration test, I don't know the named routes because the routes.rb has not been revised yet. Or I should know but I don't care it at that moment.

When rspec told me "no matching route", I say, nice, let me generate the controller and check routes.rb.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to be consistent between your application code and test code, so I would say either use named routes in both or not-named-routes in both. Since Rails seems to want you to use named routes over hard-coded paths, I would say use named routes in both places.

Comment: @JasonSwett, thanks for your point :) I added my opinion in answer.

Comment: Interesting point. I'm now much less sure that my position is right.